# How to have a list of tags and below it other items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to have something like this:

[image: tag list that grows with more items]

And below it some text, images, and other stuff.So basically I need a UIScrollView as the root view of my View. I thought to add a UICollectionView to add the tags because I dont want to manage adding constraints between items, the thing is I dont know the height that this UICollectionView should be, and I dont want to manually set the height resulting in another vertical scrolling inside my UIScrollView. Which is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Collection view is good at this.You can calculate cell width and use kinds of collection view cell to do this.For example,you can calculate label size just like this:

```
 let rect = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: CGFloat.max), options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,.UsesFontLeading], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)], context: nil)
```

Comment: And how i know the collectionView height?

Comment: @Godfather UIScrollView can't get their size before subviews has layout.So set its height to contentOffset.y after subviews layout.

Comment: now i got the items inside the CollectionView using boundingRect. This is OK. But now, how can i set the height of the CollectionView to avoid verticall scrolling?

Comment: @Godfather [CATransation setDisableActions:YES] and after change height set NO.

Comment: @Godfather Just close auto animation for a little while.Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you one really good library to work with tag like view

TagListview : Simple and highly customizable iOS tag list view, in Swift.  [link of github](https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView)